# Where does dvipdfm look for font .pfb files?

Tags: fonts, dvipdf

Where does [`dvipdfm`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/dviware/dvipdfm) (version 0.13.2c on Windows) look for font `.pfb` files? It looks in the current working directory, but I have not managed to make it look elsewhere (specifically, in the `/TeX/fonts` directory).

Or is the expected location of a `.pfb` file related to the `.tfm` file and cannot be influenced after the `.dvi` file has been created?

(I use a standalone `dvipdfm` together with a self-compiled Pascal version of TeX, none of the standardized packages.)

Comment: `texmf/fonts/type1` should work (where "texmf" is e.g. texmf-dist or texmflocal or some other texmf root).

Comment: How does `dvipdfm` know the texmf root? Must I set an environment variable?

Comment: Depends on your texsystem. In texlive it uses kpathsea like all other tex programs. A number of texmf roots are predeclared and you can add another one with `tlmgr conf auxtrees add`

Comment: Yes, but I use a standalone `dvipdfm`, not a "texsystem".

Comment: then I can't help you.

Comment: With my self-compiled Pascal version of TeX. I have a standalone TeX, but no fully-fledged TeX system.

Comment: OK, assuming the dvipdfm is using kpathse for file searching it should look in the T1FONTS env variable which in texlive defaults to `T1FONTS = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/fonts/type1//;$OSFONTDIR//`

Comment: Environment variable `T1FONTS` does not help in my case. I don't have `kpathse` installed  either (unless it is part of `dvipdfm`).